# Python random.sample same as random.choice with IF Statement

Tags: python, random

I'm working on a random suggestion script.  I came across random.sample in my search for how to make sure I don't have repeats in my generated list.  Is it the same thing as if I were to use an if statement to test the resultant against the existing list?  The number of outputs is set by the user, and the output should be random but not duplicate.  Here is my code:

```
import random
def myRandom():
    myOutput = input("How many suggestions would you like?")
    outList = list()
    counter = 1
    myDict = {
    "The First":1988,
    "The Second:": 1992,
    "The Third": 1974,
    "The Fourth": 1935,
    "The Fifth":2012,
    "The Six":2001,
    "The Seventh": 1994,
    "The Eighth":2004,
    "The Ninth": 2010,
    "The Tenth": 2003}
    while counter <= myOutput:
        thePick = random.choice(myDict.keys())
        if thePick in outList:
            pass
        else:
            outList.append(thePick)
            counter = counter + 1
    print "These are your suggestions: {0}".format(outList)
myRandom()
```

I'm not receiving any duplicates in my output list, so is this what random.sample is supposed to do as well?

Comment: You can simply use a `set` instead of a `list`.

Comment: @mattm No, that won't work. You'll increment the counter, even though for a duplicate value, it wouldn't be inserted into the set. (If you're talking about changing nothing other than`set` where `list` would have been, then it would have no impact of any kind on this code (aside from needing to use `add` instead of `append`) ... so I assume you must be suggesting use of `set` to try to "eliminate" the `if... else` section and just always try to `add` and allow the `set` logic to handle ignoring duplicates on under the hood.) You also have to consider that downstream code may require a `list`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions.  This really helps, I'm still pretty new to Python, and as I'm sure you can tell I still do things in a pretty clunky roundabout way in order to get it working.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you should use `random.sample()`. It will make your code cleaner and as a bonus you get a performance increase.

Performance issues with your loop solution:
a) It has to check in the output list before choosing any number
b) does rejection sampling, so the expected time will be higher as the input number approaches the length of the list.

```
def myRandom():
    myOutput = input("How many suggestions would you like?")
    myDict = {
    "The First":1988,
    "The Second:": 1992,
    "The Third": 1974,
    "The Fourth": 1935}
    outList = random.sample(myDict, myOutput)
    print "These are your suggestions: {0}".format(outList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a single call to `random.sample()` will do the trick:

```
outList = random.sample(myDict.keys(), myOutput)
```

You can remove the following lines from your code:

```
outList = list()
counter = 1
```

as well as the entire `while` loop.